# intervention analysis using Dummy data

Tags: r, time-series

I am working on a homework assignment using intervention analysis. The question is:

Generate a simulation of the difference equation y_t=a_0+〖a_1 y〗_(t-1)+〖c_0 z〗_t+x_t where x_t is the forcing process x_t=w_t, w_t is a white noise, and 〖|a〗_1 |<1. Define the intervention variable z_t as binary (0,1) but you may choose the start time of the intervention; assume the intervention lasts for 2 units of time.

So I wrote this code:

```
set.seed(50)
y <- w <- rnorm(200, sd=1)
alpha0 <- 1
alpha1 <- 0.9
cee0 <- 1
z <-rep(0, 200)
for (t in 1:200) {z[t] <- ifelse( t = 78:79,1,0)}
```

So the intervention would occur at the 78th and 79th instant.

But this does not work. I keep getting this error/warning message: 
In z[t] <- ifelse(t = 77:78, 1, 0) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I have tried the analysis using a continuous intervention at the 100th instant and it works fine:

```
z <-rep(0, 200)
for (t in 1:200) {z[t] <- ifelse( t > 100,1,0)}
```

So why does the t > 100 work but t = 77:78 not work? Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your command as follows.

```
for (t in 1:200) {z[t] <- ifelse( t %in% 78:79,1,0)}

> z
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [57] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[113] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[169] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```